# Problems finding main class with gradle jar file

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, build.gradle, gradlew

I've seen many people with "Could not find or load main class" errors when making jar files with Gradle. I have gone through many of the forums and have not found a solution that works for me yet. Following an online tutorial, I was able to set up a Gradle project in VSCode and add dependencies for a basic hello world program. Link to the tutorial I was following here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwdkyrnJQsg
This worked for me no problem but when I finished my much larger program, it doesn't find my Main.class file. Here's my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'application'
}

application
{
    mainClass = 'Main'
}

java
{
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_12
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_12
}

project.configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true);
version = '1.0.0'
mainClassName = 'Main'

sourceSets
{
    main 
    {
        java
        {
            srcDirs 'src/main/java'
        }
    }
}

repositories
{
    mavenCentral()
    maven
    {
        url = 'https://licensespring-maven.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/'
    }
}

dependencies
{
    implementation 'com.licensespring:licensespring-license-client:2.1.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.0.0-alpha-6'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.harawata/appdirs
    implementation group: 'net.harawata', name: 'appdirs', version: '1.2.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna-platform
    implementation group: 'net.java.dev.jna', name: 'jna-platform', version: '5.6.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna
    implementation group: 'net.java.dev.jna', name: 'jna', version: '5.6.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '2.0.0-alpha1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.7'
}

jar
{
    manifest
    {
        attributes(
            "Main-Class": "$mainClassName",
            "Class-Path": configurations.implementation.collect {it.name}.join(' ')
        )
    }
    dependsOn('dependencies')
    from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

In `src/main/java/` I have my Main.java file with the main method along with all my other .java files. When I run `gradlew clean build`, my `.class` files show up under `build/classes/java/main`.
Just to clarify, when I run `java -jar './build/libs/myApplication.jar'` I get the `Could not find or load main class Main` error. Let me know if you need any more specifics.

UPDATE: Switched over to Intellij again and I am getting errors involving the Main Manifest Attribute. I checked the outputted jar and the Manifest file is indeed packaged and it does have a Main Manifest Attribute. PLEASE HELP ME SOMEONE!

Comment: I'll take it you are new in java and will advice you use an IDE with a stronger community like eclipse.  Either way, try to check if the main method is below other methods within the class as it should be. Or share the code for clarification

Comment: I'm not really new to java, but I am new to using Gradle for sure. I originally coded this program in IntelliJ IDEA but had much worse results trying to compile it through their IDE. That's why I tried the more manual approach with VSCode. The main method is just under the class. So the code looks like this: `public class Main { public static void main(String[] args) {//Do stuff} }`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving source set and full package name for main?
It should look something like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src/main/java'
        }
    }
}

project.configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)

jar{
    manifest {
        attributes(
                "Main-Class": "com.xyz.Main",
                "Class-Path":  configurations.implementation.collect { it.name }.join(' ')
        )
    }
    dependsOn ('dependencies')
}
```

Comment: Share directory structure till main class or git link, if issue persists.

Comment: I've changed my build.gradle file in the way you suggested. unfortunately, after another `gradlew clean build` it gave me the same error. I extracted the jar file to a new folder. In the root of that folder was all of my `.class` files including `Main.class`.

Comment: Here is a github link: [MyRepo](https://github.com/CadenSounart/UltimateAttendance)

Comment: I have edited my comment which helped me resolve above issue. However, I ran into new error -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/licensespring/LicenseSpringConfiguration You are using Gradle 6.6 which is a recent upgrade. You might want to look at gradle documentation docs.gradle.org/6.6.1/userguide/publishing_setup.html

Comment: I originally had that same error with the LicenseSpring API. I found that it was because I never told Gradle how to pack the dependencies into the jar file. I read everywhere that I needed to add `from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }`. Since your new code has this line removed, that error comes back. I tried adding that line back in and the `NoClassDefError` is removed, but the `Could not find or load main class Main` error came back. Would you advise switching to an older Gradle version, and if so, which one?

Comment: After extracting the `.jar` file with your fixes, I can verify that none of the dependencies are inside the jar. Only the `.class` and manifest folders are.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue to create runnable jar. I could solve it with following example

Solution 1 : Create a fat jar with all dependencies.

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
 manifest {attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.gradle.App'}
 from {
       configurations.compile.collect
       { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
 }with jar
}
```

Solution 2 : Create a runnable jar with dependencies copied to a directory and setting the class path

```
def dependsDir = "${buildDir}/libs/dependencies/"
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
   from configurations.compile
   into "${dependsDir}"
}

task createJar(dependsOn: copyDependencies, type: Jar) {
   manifest {
      attributes(
       'Main-Class': 'com.example.gradle.App',
       'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect
             { 'dependencies/' + it.getName() }.join(' ')
      )}
     with jar
}
```

Read more on this with an example [here](https://jafarmlp.medium.com/a-simple-java-project-with-gradle-2c323ae0e43d)